# Appending content simply with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my mind, this should work.

I'm trying to get all the paragraphs inside `.one`, to be duplicated and after the first few paragraphs.

http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/B4f5b/

I have this:

```
<div class="one">
    <p>one</p>
    <p>two</p>
    <p>three</p>
</div>
```

I want this:

```
<div class="one">
    <p>one</p>
    <p>two</p>
    <p>three</p>
    <p>one</p>
    <p>two</p>
    <p>three</p>
</div>
```

And I am using:

```
$('.one p').appendTo('.one');
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

`$('.one p').clone().appendTo('.one');`

[.clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) does exactly what it sounds like; clones the selected element(s) (and its descendants) to which you can append as needed.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/B4f5b/2/